# How to save a field in members ? Improve of the shop form

Tags: xml, odoo

I would like to add a field birthdate in the shop form

The main xml is this one

```
https://jsfiddle.net/NadirB21/ubtvkfc4/
```

[img] http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/966482shop.png [/img]

I add

```
<div t-attf-class="form-group #{error.get('birthdate') and 'has-error' or ''} col-lg-6">
    <label class="control-label" for="birthdate">Birthdate</label>
    <input type="text" name="birthdate" class="form-control" t-att-value="checkout.get('birthdate')"/>
</div>
```

And i add

```
t-att-data-shipping_birthdate="shipping.birthdate"
```

and

```
<div t-attf-class="form-group #{error.get('shipping_birthdate') and 'has-error' or ''} col-lg-6">
    <label class="control-label" for="shipping_birthdate" style="font-weight: normal"> Date De Naissance</label>
    <input type="text" name="shipping_birthdate" class="form-control" t-att-value="checkout.get('shipping_birthdate', '')" t-att-readonly=" 'readonly' if shipping_id &gt;= 0 else ''"/>
</div>
```

I also active this field in the module member

[img] http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/455128modulenotsave.png [/img]

When i confirm the shop, the field is not display in the confirm form and it is not create in the module member.
What i have to add in the aim to save this field in the module member ?

Answer (score 0):

I add images in the aim to explain the problem.
There is a problem of interaction between the module member and the shop form.